# PHP: Check link content and display appropriate text on button

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm creating a site in Wordpress where some PDFs will be uploaded for users to download. Now I'm struggling a bit with PHP to figure out a way to display two different texts on the download button, depending on wether a PDF has been uploaded yet or not.

The button is currently made this way:

```
<a href="<?php the_field('presentation_pdf'); ?>" target="_new" class="small round button">Download</a>
```

What I need help to figure out now is a php-function where it checks if the link is to a PDF-file or not, and display the texts: Download (Link leads to a PDF-file) or "Not yet uploaded" if the link is "empty".

Comment: If PDF has not been uploaded yet, at that time what is it giving in `href` ?

Comment: If there isn't a PDF uploaded it will actually give the user a broken link, so I need to figure out that as well. Because right now it will just reload the page in a new tab since there is nothing specified in "href=".

Answer (score 0):

assuming your pdf is saved as a `postmeta`, you can check if meta exist and then make the conditional:

```
$pdf = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pdf', TRUE);
if(!empty($pdf)): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $pdf; ?>">Download</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="nopdf">No PDF</span>
<?php ?>
```

Comment: This looks very much like what I picture in my head to begin with, thanks! :) The PDF is added through a file upload field created with Advanced Custom Fields. That allows me to output the http-link to the file by using
     <?php the_field('presentation_pdf'); ?>
Is there a way I could check if the file is present with PHP or will it be easier to use postmeta to upload the file instead?